# Oracle 11g database server password rollbacks

Tags: oracle

Hi everyone,
            I installed oracle 11g Database server in windows 2003 server. I changed the password. It works very well when I start at first. After restarting, the password is not at all working. Please do guide me to settle the issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
H. Noordeen

Comment: Please be aware that in Oracle 11G passwords are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes but only if you enable it by Oracle Parameter `sec_case_sensitive_logon`

Comment: "Rolls back" or "not at all working"? Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used special character like "@" in your password, then try to log in by providing your password within double quotes

e.g. -

```
c:> SQLPLUS username/"pass@word"@database
```

Then you can set new password using

```
alter user <username> identified by <new_password>;
```

You can change using this command through Admin log in as well.